# How can I install the htpasswd utility in Red Hat / Scientific Linux?

Tags: apache-2.2, htpasswd

For apache, there is the [htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html) utility, which can be used to generate encrypted passwords for .htaccess access restriction etc. In Ubuntu I can install it via the apache2-utils package, but in Scientific Linux (Red Hat) I find only the following package, when I do `yum search htpasswd`:

```
perl-Apache-Htpasswd.noarch : Manage Unix crypt-style password file
```

but this does not seem to be the package I'm looking for, since it does not include the htpasswd command, and also when I do `apt-cache search htpasswd` in Ubuntu, I get:

```
libapache-htpasswd-perl - Manage Unix crypt-style password file
lighttpd - A fast webserver with minimal memory footprint
nanoweb - HTTP server written in PHP
apache2-utils - utility programs for webservers
```

... where the first one is quite obviously the one corresponding to the one I found for Red Hat above(?).

So, is there any equivalent to the apache2-utils package, or any other package including the htpassd utility, for Red Hat/Scientific Linux? At least I can't find it ...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try
  `yum provides \*bin/htpasswd`

Comment: But don't forget to escape the wildcard.

Comment: Ah, thanks! (Even better than just providing the answer ... helping me to help myself :)). So ... turns out that it is provided with the httpd package itself. Well, that explains it. (Was trying to use the htpasswd from a server which did not have apache installed, but only the file system to be published on www ...)

Comment: @Ignacio: Worked without escaping too ... but maybe that depends on which shell you run ...

Comment: I learned something too, although to be honest I don't know why you're supposed to. It appears to work without escaping in CentOS 5.6, but I guess there's another reason for it.

Comment: It all depends on whether or not something matches the pattern you use. `mkdir -p bogusbin/htpasswd`

Answer (score 79):

It's `yum install httpd-tools`.
Just found it today.

Comment: In CentOS at least, `httpd-tools` *does* provide htpasswd. I found it using `yum provides \*bin/htpasswd` ;)

Great way to get htpasswd without installing the httpd server (often not desirable if you're running another web server already, or don't want to run a web server)

Comment: RHEL6 - # yum install httpd-tools does have htpasswd utility. Run yum provides \*bin/htpasswd, and it will show that https-tools provides the htpasswd utility.

Comment: no working this yum provides \*bin/htpasswd and this yum install httpd-tools any solution for centos 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure where the utility is located, use:

```
whereis htpasswd
```

For my server, it was installed on `/usr/bin/htpasswd`

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This command searches for which packages provide the requested dependency of file. This also takes wildcards for files.

```
yum whatprovides */htpasswd
```