# How do I change Dovecot virtual user passwords?

Tags: centos, dovecot

I used one web based control panel to create some virtual users for Dovecot. That control panel no longer works so I need to do this manually.

I need to reset the password for one (virtual) user which is listed in `dovecot.passwd` file. The file uses `CRYPT` schema. How do I reset that password?

So the question boils down to - what can use to convert plain text password to `CRYPT` encrypted format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Apache utility [`htpasswd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html).  It uses `crypt()` to encrypt passwords by default on Linux platforms.  The following will prompt you for the new password for the user `jscott` and will update the file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd`.

`htpasswd /etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd jscott`

Comment: Word of caution. If you are using the same file as userdb too then it will have other fields which the above method will remove. So instead I guess the safer way is to use `htpasswd -n jscott`. This will print the encrypted password to console. Copy that manually into the passwd file.

Comment: If you have CentOS, you might not have htpasswd `yum install httpd-tools` via http://serverfault.com/a/568771/82801 Also, use the `-c` switch to create the file if you don't have `dovecot.passwd` yet.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `doveadm` utility that comes with Dovecot:

```
$ doveadm pw -s CRYPT
Enter new password: 
Retype new password: 
{CRYPT}1cElWVzS3.EVg
```

Comment: Does this make the dovecot password independent of the linux user password?

Comment: @User: Not by itself.  This is for virtual users; system users use the system password.  See http://wiki2.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers

Comment: Can a virtual user and a system user have the same username?

Answer (score 5):

or to avoid the prompts do:

doveadm pw -s CRYPT -p yourpassword -u user

Comment: This is generally a bad practice however, as the line (including the plain text password) will show in your shell history, running commands, etc.

Answer (score 1):

doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT

is also good.