# How do I change Dovecot user passwords stored in a database?

Tags: dovecot

I have a setup running [AuthDatabse](http://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL) configuration. All works fine from a webmail side, but if I want to use `doveadm` to change the user password, the database is not affected.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doveadm` cannot be used to change user passwords, you have to do this through some other system.

- `doveadm user` can only look up user information
- `doveadm auth` can be used to *verify* credentials
- `doveadm pw` calculates password hashes for different schemes, but does not apply any changes

[`doveadm pw -u [username]` is only used and required for Digest-MD5](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Pw#section_options):

> `-u user`
>
> When the DIGEST-MD5 scheme is used, also the user name must be given, because the user name is a part of the generated hash. For more information about Digest-MD5 please read also: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms/DigestMD5

Comment: Thanks for explanation. My knowledge regarding password reset was based on that http://serverfault.com/questions/357053/how-do-i-change-dovecot-virtual-user-passwords

Comment: This question was only about "convert[ing] plain text password to CRYPT encrypted format", not actually _setting_ the passphrase.

Comment: Is there some command out there that actually edits the dovecot users file or do I need to roll my own script to do this?  htpasswd doesn't cut it, it doesn't use the same crypt doveadm uses and the lines don't seem to be the same format to me.